# spring autowire multiple implementation

Tags: java, spring

I need to autowire interface which has couple of implementation. I'm using @Qualifier to achieve this-

**Interface DataSourceConfig**

```
public interface DataSourceConfig {
  DataSource getDataSource();
}
```

**Implementation 1:**

```
@Configuration("mysql")
public class MySqlDataSourceConfig implements DataSourceConfig {

@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    System.out.println("MySQL datasource");

    //some implementation

    return dataSource;
 }
}
```

**Implementation 2:**

```
@Configuration("hsql")
public class HsqlDataSourceConfig implements DataSourceConfig {

@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    System.out.println("hsql dataSource");
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).addScript(
            "classpath:database/schema.sql").addScript(
            "classpath:database/datascript.sql").build();
   }
}
```

**Client:**

```
@Configuration
public class Client {

 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("hsql")
 DataSourceConfig hsqlDataSource;

 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("mysql")
 DataSourceConfig mysqlDataSource;

}
```

Only one datasource (mysqlDataSource) is being created and i see the following message in my log. It's in INFO mode though -

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition Overriding bean definition for bean 'hsqlDataSource':
```

Comment: Don't confuse the name of the `@Configuration` bean as the name of your `DataSource` bean.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis If i give name to bean and add qualifier based on the bean name, it doesn't autowire any of the data source -org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.sample.config.DataSourceConfig] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.

Comment: What I'm saying is that `@Qualifier("hsql")` is actually referencing the `HsqlDataSourceConfig` bean defined with `@Configuration("hsql")`. Please post an MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem of multiple same types (DataSource), we have to use autowiring mode "by name". The default is "by type". Set the attribute "name" to your @Bean annotation.

**Implementation 1:**

```
@Configuration
public class MySqlDataSourceConfig implements DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean(name="mysql")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        System.out.println("MySQL datasource");
        MysqlDataSource dataSource= new MysqlDataSource();
        // ... dataSource parameters
        return dataSource;
     }
}
```

**Implementation 2:**

```
@Configuration
public class HsqlDataSourceConfig implements DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean(name="hsql")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
     System.out.println("hsql dataSource");
     return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).addScript(
        "classpath:database/schema.sql").addScript(
        "classpath:database/datascript.sql").build();
   }
}
```

**Client:**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Client {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("hsql")
    private javax.sql.DataSource hsqlDataSource;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mysql")
    private javax.sql.DataSource mySqlDataSource;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. Got this exception -     No qualifying bean of type [com.sample.config.DataSourceConfig] found for dependency: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), 
@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=hsql)}